# Dynamic span text change when image carousel switch

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel and I want when image from slider change the text(span with `class="image-title"`) to have the value of alt image active .

For example if image1 is active the span will be like that `<span>Alt of image 1</span>`,
when image 2 is active the span will be

```
<span>Alt of image 2</span>
```

How can I do that ?

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/1598/

Answer (score 0):

1. Your images don't contain alt attributes, so you need to add them in order to get the text in the alt attributes.
2. I created a function switchText. It takes the text of the alt attribute of the active image and sets it as text in the span element:

   ```
   function switchText() {
       $('span').text($('.active img').attr('alt'));   
   }
   ```
3. You need to call this new function at the bottom of the callback function when the "slid" event happens:

   ```
   // bind 'slid' function
   $('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {

       // remove active class

       $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

       // get index of currently active item
       var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();

       // select currently active item and add active class
       $('.carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');
       switchText();
   });
   ```
4. These changes switch the text, when the slid event is invoked. But at the beginning you won't have the text in the span element. To get the text at the beginning you have to the switchText function call directly after you initialized the carousel, too:

   ```
   // invoke the carousel
   $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
   });
   // use alt text from first image at the beginning
   switchText();
   ```